# Pytextrank - avoid lowercasing tags into key phrases extraction

Tags: nlp, spacy, pytextrank

I want to avoid lowercasing tags in pytextrank. Any suggestions on how that can be achieved?

Comment: Could you please give an example of what you mean in terms of "lowercasing tags" ?  I'm lead committer for [PyTextRank](https://github.com/DerwenAI/pytextrank) and we'd like to add features or support for identified use cases. Do you need instances of the raw text for a phrase?

Answer (score 1):

As of **PyTextRank** version 2.1.0 (released on 2021-01-31) when an application iterates through the ranked phrases, such as:

```
for phrase in doc._.phrases[:10]:
    print(phrase.text)
```

... the default text for each phrase is its most popular instance appearing in the document. That's what gets set in the `text` field of the `Phrase` data class.

However, check out the `chunks` field for **all** instances of the phrase that occur in the document. Since these are extracted from the document's raw text, these do not get forced to lowercase.

OTOH, when the algorithm constructs its internal *lemma graph* data structure, the lemmatized tokens are forced to lowercase. However, you don't need to use the lemma graph as the end results. Perhaps that may be some source of confusion?